# How to implement a Checkbox select all in a Grouped Listview control WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the below code to handle the Checkbox event, basically, I want to handle select all and unselect from parent and child checkboxes. I was able to achieve this for Parent/Group level Checkbox, but struggling to find a Parent checkbox when a sub-item checkbox is checked/unchecked. Can someone please help me in handling this.

```
List<WorkSheetList> wbList = new List<WorkSheetList>();
public CrossShtCompute()
{
   InitializeComponent();  
   wbList.Add(new WorkSheetList() { WorkbookName = "Workbook A", IsChecked = true, SheetName = "WorkSheet A", IsSelected = false, CellValue = 100 });
   wbList.Add(new WorkSheetList() { WorkbookName = "Workbook B", IsChecked = true, SheetName = "WorkSheet B", IsSelected = false, CellValue = 200 });
   wbList.Add(new WorkSheetList() { WorkbookName = "Workbook A", IsChecked = true, SheetName = "WorkSheet C", IsSelected = false, CellValue = 300 });
   wbList.Add(new WorkSheetList() { WorkbookName = "Workbook B", IsChecked = true, SheetName = "WorkSheet D", IsSelected = false, CellValue = 400 });

   lvUsers.ItemsSource = wbList;

   CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
   PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("WorkbookName");
   view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
}

private void HandleCheckBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var checkBox = e.OriginalSource as CheckBox;
    
   if (checkBox != null && checkBox.Name == "HeaderCheckBox")
   {
      var group = (CollectionViewGroup)checkBox.DataContext;
 
      foreach (WorkSheetList item in group.Items)
      {
        item.IsChecked = (bool)checkBox.IsChecked;
      }
  }
  else if(checkBox != null && checkBox.Tag.ToString() == "")
  {
      // need help here
  }
```

}

// Modal Class

```
public class WorkSheetList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _IsChecked;
        private bool _IsSelected;
        public double? _CellValue;

        public string WorkbookName { get; set; }
        public string SheetName { get; set; }

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _IsChecked; }
            set
            {
                _IsChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _IsSelected; }
            set
            {
                _IsSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        public double? CellValue
        {
            get { return _CellValue; }
            set
            {
                _CellValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CellValue");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

// UI

```
<ListView Name="lvUsers" ButtonBase.Click="HandleCheckBoxClick" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" Workbook" Width="200">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="" Margin="35,2,0,0" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SheetName}" Margin="5,2" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" Range Value" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CellValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2,2" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" Margin="0,7,0,0">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <CheckBox x:Name="HeaderCheckBox" Tag="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="True" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="DarkGreen" Margin="5,5,0,0"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text=" Sheet(s)" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a reference to the parent `CheckBox` using the `VisualTreeHelper`:

```
private void HandleCheckBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = e.OriginalSource as CheckBox;

    if (checkBox != null && checkBox.Name == "HeaderCheckBox")
    {
        var group = (CollectionViewGroup)checkBox.DataContext;

        foreach (WorkSheetList item in group.Items)
        {
            item.IsChecked = (bool)checkBox.IsChecked;
        }
    }
    else if (checkBox != null && checkBox.Tag.ToString() == "")
    {
        var expander = FindParent<Expander>(checkBox);
        var headerCheckBox = expander.FindName("HeaderCheckBox") as CheckBox;
        var group = (CollectionViewGroup)expander.DataContext;
        headerCheckBox.IsChecked = group.Items.OfType<WorkSheetList>().All(x => x.IsChecked);
    }
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null)
        return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Comment: one other question, is this the best way to handle this, or is there a way to handle this by complete MVVM?