# WPF - Checkbox to Select All Rows in Group

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I'm making a WPF and C# application using MVVM.  I'm presenting all of the "PropertyItem" classes to the user using a DataGrid; they are group using a ListCollectionView.  I have checkboxes in each row so that the user can turn off individual "PropertyItem."  Does anyone know how to have a checkbox in the Expander.Header so that I can turn off a whole group of properties at once?

Here is the XAML code I have so far.  The expandable groups is working quite well.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsTasks">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Pset"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="propertiesTable"
            ItemsSource="{Binding chosenConceptProperties}"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
            Grid.Row="3" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            Margin="0,25,0,0" CellEditEnding="propertiesTable_CellEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="10*" MinWidth="250" Header="Property Name" Binding="{Binding PropertyName}" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="10" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="10*" MinWidth="250" Header="Mapping" Binding="{Binding Mapping}" IsReadOnly="False" FontSize="10" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*" MinWidth="50" Header="On/Off" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding On}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True" Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="#2a5fa4" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

For some context, here is some of the c# code.  I don't think you really know where the data is coming from, but the class structure is important:

```
private EntityConcept _chosenConcept = new EntityConcept(); 

chosenConceptProperties = new ListCollectionView(chosenConcept.propertyList);
chosenConceptProperties.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Pset"));


 public class EntityConcept
    {
        private string _Name;

        public ObservableCollection<PropertyItem> propertyList
        {
            get
            {
                return _propertyList;
            }
            set
            {
                _propertyList = value;
            }
        }             

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }

    }

public class PropertyItem
    {
        private string _PropertyName = String.Empty;
        private string _Pset = String.Empty;
        private string _Mapping = "";
        private bool _On = true;

        public string PropertyName
        {
            get
            {
                return _PropertyName;
            }
            set
            {
                _PropertyName = value;
            }
        }
        public string Pset
        {
            get
            {
                return _Pset ;
            }
            set
            {
                _Pset = value;
            }
        }
        public string Mapping
        {
            get
            {
                return _Mapping;
            }
            set
            {
                _Mapping = value;
            }
        }
        public bool On
        {
            get
            {
                return _On;
            }
            set
            {
                _On = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is currently what the datagrid looks like when it is populated with data:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575621/how-to-implement-a-checkbox-select-all-in-a-grouped-listview-control-wpf

Comment: @ASh this doesn't seem to work for ListCollectionView within a dataGrid.  Maybe there is something wrong with my design pattern, but it doesn't update the datagrid.